# PowerShell regex replace. Starts with < and ends with >

Tags: regex, powershell

I have one big string that I need to parse with PowerShell.

Need This:

```
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve">powershell -C </w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00642D9D"><w:instrText>;</w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="009A58AF"><w:instrText xml:space="preserve">echo </w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00183CB3"><w:instrText>\"</w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="009A58AF"><w:instrText>https:/</w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="004018F3"><w:instrText>/</w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="009A58AF"><w:instrText>sec.gov/
```

To turn into:

```
powershell -C ;echo \"https://sec.gov/
```

Can't figure out how to turn
    (<.+?>)
into a powershell regex query

Comment: `-replace '<.+?>'`?

Comment: OMG.... You made that seem way too easy. Thank you!